# Почему TypeError: container.getElementsByTagName is not a function

Tags: javascript, dom

На страницу динамически добавляется (не знаю верно так говорить о нём или нет, но не в этом суть) узел (тег div с классом "shop"). в нём создаётся ещё три дива.
При нажатии кнопки "выхода" этот узел должен удалиться. Делаю это так, на кнопку повешена функция:

```js
stopShop: function(_context){
  var container = document.getElementsByClassName('shop');
  var contDiv = container.getElementsByTagName('div');
  //console.log(container);
  container.removeChild(contDiv);
}
```

но выпадает ошибка  TypeError: container.getElementsByTagName is not a function, помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

потому, что  `getElementsByClassName` возвращает [коллекцию](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) (Returns an array-like object по версии мозиллы), а не элемент - поскольку элементов с одинаковым классом может быть > 1.

Tебе нужно обратиться к элементу в этой коллекции чтобы использовать `element.getElementsByTagName()`